# Beautifulsoup Title приходит знаками вопроса

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть такой отрывок кода.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://nk.ru', timeout=1)
r.encoding='utf8'
html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
titles = soup.title.text
print(titles)
```

Обычно всё нормально выводится, а в этой ситуации в `print()` выводятся знаки вопроса. Подскажите, что не так делаю?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import requests

if __name__ == '__main__':
    html = Soup(requests.get('https://nk.ru').content, 'html.parser')

    print(html.title.text)
# Народная Компания - Интернет-магазин бытовой техники и электроники Хабаровск
```

Answer (score 0):

очевидный ответ, не та кодировка на сайте. Если посмотреть код сайта видно что там не `utf-8` , а  `windows-1251` кодировка. Замените ее в строчке `r.encoding='utf8'`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А как быть в ситуации если сайтов будет несколько и все с разной кодировкой?

Comment: @Ivan это как?В любом же случае для другого сайта будете писать другой парсер. Парсить другие  данные с других тегов и т.д. в основном везде сейчас utf-8 используют вроде как

Comment: Ну например есть список из 100 сайтов нужно взять только title а кодировка на них разная?

Comment: @Ivan, в большинстве случаев сайты сами отдают ответ с указанием правильной кодировки, поэтому обычно явно указывать кодировку не нужно. По факту вы сами поменяли правильную кодировку на неправильную: если посмотреть поле `r.encoding` до того как вы заменили значение в нем на `utf-8` - там будет `cp1251`.

Comment: Ok спасибо за ваши ответы!